# Node express bad practice?

Tags: node.js, express

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to standardize my `try {} catch() {}` block across all my routes.

### I created a Controller class as follows:

```js
const { handleRouteError } = require('../handleRouteError');

class Controller {
  async tryFunction(promise, onSuccess, onFail) {
    try {
      const data = await promise;
      onSuccess(data);
    } catch (error) {
      handleRouteError(error);
      onFail(error);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Controller;
```

### And I'm using it like this in my router:

```js
const { getDays } = require('./controllers/getDays');
const controller = new Controller;

router.get('/days', async function getDayDays(req, res, next) {
  await controller.tryFunction(
    getDays(res.locals.user_id),
    (data) => res.json(data),
    (err) => next(err)
  );
});
```

### My questions:

1. Is it bad practice to pass the `onSuccess` and `onFail` function as I have done? All opinions welcome!
2. Will it eat up a lot of memory on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to stick to the built in error handling rather than inventing my own.

If your intention is to call `handleRouterError` with the error before passing the error to the caller you could do something like this:

```
class Controller {
  async resolve(promise) {
    try {
      return await promise;
    } catch (error) {
      handleRouteError(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

And consume the `resolve` method like this:

```
const { getDays } = require('./controllers/getDays');
const controller = new Controller;

router.get('/days', async function getDayDays(req, res, next) {
  try {
    res.json(await controller.resolve(getDays(res.locals.user_id)));
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
});
```